Utilizing GPU in MacBook Pro M1 for ML Models in Jupyter Notebook
I am using a MacBook Pro M1 model for running machine learning (ML) models in Jupyter Notebook. I would like to know if this setup automatically utilizes the MacBook's default GPU for computations, or if there are additional settings or configurations needed to enable GPU usage.
I haven't tried anything yet. I'm expecting that if I use a MacBook Pro M1 model for running ML models in Jupyter Notebook, it would automatically utilize the MacBook's default GPU for computations. However, I'm unsure if any additional settings or configurations are required to enable this.
